# Payable function transaction failing

Tags: solidity, transactions, payable

Please see the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.1;

contract Crowdfund {
    uint fundLimit = 3 ether;
    bool contractOpen = true;

    function donate() external payable { 
        require(contractOpen, "Contract has stopped recieving funds");
        require(address(this).balance + msg.value <= fundLimit, "Can't send specified amount");
    }
}
```

If I try to send 2 (or) 3 ether then the transaction is failing;

```
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "Can't send specified amount".
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Ideally, the transaction of 2 (or) 3 ether should not fail because `fundLimit` is set to 3 ether. And initially, the contract balance is 0.

I am unable to know the reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest way to represent the value of your smart contract is to use a variable rather than `address(this).balance`. This can easily be manipulated by sending ether to your contract (even if you don't have any fallback or receive functions).

```
uint public balance = 0;
```

And whenver you deposit money, `balance += msg.value`.

That being said, your require fails because when you send 2 ether, your account balance is immediately becoming 2 ether. And adding `msg.value` to `address(this).balance` makes it 4 and fails the check. You can test what I said by returning the `address(this).balance + msg.value`. What I would do instead:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Crowdfund {
    uint fundLimit = 3 ether;
    bool contractOpen = true;

   uint public balance = 0;

    function donate() external payable { 
        require(contractOpen, "Contract has stopped recieving funds");
        balance += msg.value;
        require(balance <= fundLimit, "Too much!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue I just used address(this).balance. Actually, I am playing around with the force send / self-destruct vulnerability so didn't actually want to use a variable as you suggested.

Comment: yeap, selfdestruct vulnerability is exactly what I was saying.